# Event cannot trigger when the transaction is done

Tags: contract-development, web3js, events

My contract location is [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x96d2a2978d52287c2dfff0e2a40d12181223303c#code)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Coursetro {

   string fName;
   uint age;
   event Instructor(
       string name,
       uint age
    );

   function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
       Instructor(_fName, _age);    
   }

   function getInstructor() view public returns (string, uint) {
       return (fName, age);
   }

}
```

MY JS script

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        //console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        //TO-DO
        //Pop Up Model And Ask User download MetaMask       
        console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
    startApp();
});


function startApp() {
    var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract(
        [{ "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_fName", "type": "string" }, { "name": "_age", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "setInstructor", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getInstructor", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "string" }, { "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": false, "name": "name", "type": "string" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "age", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Instructor", "type": "event" }]
    );

    var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x96d2a2978d52287c2DffF0e2A40D12181223303C');

    var instructorEvent = Coursetro.Instructor({ fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' });



    instructorEvent.watch(function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
            $("#loader").hide();
            $("#instructor").html(result.args.name + ' (' + result.args.age + ' years old)');
        } else {
            $("#loader").hide();
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#loader").show();
        Coursetro.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val(), function(error, result) {
            if (!error) {


            } else
                console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
```

When I click the button to call setInstructor function and then the transaction is done, the Event is not triggered. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `watch` event and not `get` the historic events, you should change your event declaration to:

```
var instructorEvent = Coursetro.Instructor();
```

---

Otherwise it would look like this:

```
var myEvent = contractInstance.myEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});

myEvent.get((error, events) => {
    if (!error) {
        function ShowResults(event) {
            console.log('Argument 1: ' + event.args._arg1);
            console.log('Argument 2: ' + event.args._arg2);
        }
        events.forEach(ShowResults);
    } else {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not the exact answer. However, it really helps me a lot. I finally use the getTransactionReceipt function to do what I want. Thanks.